# Powershell get files that meet certain conditions

Tags: powershell, scripting

I am trying to write a PowerShell script that will retrieve a file if it contains a string "string 1" and it **doesn't** contain "string 2". I have written the following script however it is retrieving files that contain both of these strings.

```
get-childitem  -recurse -file  D:\Folder | 
where { 
Get-Content $_.FullName | Where-Object { $_ -match "string 1" -and  $_-notmatch "string 2"}
}
```

How can I get the files that meet this condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st Solution ( by changing Your Code ):

```
(Get-ChildItem "D:\Folder\*.*") |  Where-Object {(Get-Content $_.FullName) -match "string 1" -and  (Get-Content $_.FullName) -notmatch "string 2" } | select FullName
```

2nd Solution (Using Select-String):

```
(Get-ChildItem "D:\Folder\*.*") | Where-Object {(Select-String -Path $_.FullName -Pattern "string 1") -and -not(Select-String -Path $_.FullName -Pattern "string 2") }| select FullName
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do the second comparison against the entire file at once. I would use `Select-String`:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -Path D:\Folder | Where-Object { 
    (Select-String -Path $_.FullName "string1") -and -not(Select-String -Path $_.FullName "string2")
}
```